# Error when I try to create ordered SQL table

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by, teradata, create-table

I'm trying to create a volatile table in SQL with an ORDER BY and I get an error.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE orderd_dates AS
(SELECT * FROM date_table
ORDER BY id_date)
with data primary index (id_date) on commit preserve rows;
```

The error is: ORDER BY is not allowed in subqueries.

If I can't use order by, how can I create a volatile table that's ordered?

Comment: That's correct, `ORDER BY` is not allowed when forming a table expression for a subquery. You specify the order on the full select.

Comment: You can use the primary index as an implied order. There is no guarantee, but it'll likely be returned ordered with simple selects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL tables are inherently unordered. You need to explicitly use an `order by` clause when querying the table, not when creating it.

Answer (score 2):

You could add TOP 100 PERCENT to allow the ORDER BY, but the table would still be unordered, because a table is internally ordered by the Hash of the Primary Index. And if you use a NO PRIMARY INDEX TABLE and it would actually be stored in the specified order the optimizer wouldn't know about it.

The closest thing you can get is to `PARTITION BY RANGE_N(id_date BETWEEN DATE '2000-01-01' AND DATE '2050-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY`:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE orderd_dates AS
(SELECT * FROM date_table
)
WITH DATA 
PRIMARY INDEX (id_date)
PARTITION BY Range_N(id_date BETWEEN DATE '2000-01-01'
                                 AND DATE '2050-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: Ok ok. Where would the partition statement go in the syntax? When I try to replace the group by statement with the partition by statement, I get the error: "Syntax error, expected something like ')' between the word 'date_table' and the 'PARTITION' keyword.

Comment: Edited my answer, but why do you want to do that?